# Implied bit in IEEE floating point format

Tags: bit, ieee-754

Why is there an implied (or hidden) bit in IEEE floating point format? What is the purpose of it? It is mentioned in passing on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating-point_standard#Basic_formats).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [(Complete) Tutorial to Understand IEEE Floating-Point Errors](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/42980):

> "[Fraction] is the normalized fractional part of the number, normalized because the exponent is adjusted so that the leading bit is always a 1. This way, it does not have to be stored, and you get one more bit of precision. This is why there is an implied bit."

It basically allows for higher precision.

Comment: That did **NOT** help me.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that the most important thing to know is that it is not actually stored in memory:

> The format is assumed to have an implicit lead bit with value 1 unless the exponent field is stored with all zeros. Thus, **only 10 bits of the significand appear in the memory** format but the total precision is 11 bits.

So for instance in the half-precision floating point (16 bits, or 2 bytes, aka. **FP16**), there are 1 sign bit, 5 exponent bits, and 10 **actual** significand bits. `1 + 5 + 10 = 16`, and then there's the implied one extra significand bit that's always `== 1`.

[Implied bit in IEEE floating point format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8550592/implied-bit-in-ieee-floating-point-format)